# Invalid column name difficulties

Tags: sql, gridview, ado.net

Can't get my code to work. I have all the same names and i still get the same error telling me that "AwardName" is invalid. Ill list my code and stack trace below. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                runat="server"
                DataKeyNames="AwardName"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                Style="text-align: left"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                GridLines="None"
                AllowPaging="true"
                ShowFooter="true">
                <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AwardName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("AwardName") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="EditAwardName" Text='
                    <%# Bind("AwardName") %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="InsertAwardName" Text='
                    <%# Bind("AwardName") %>' />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recepient">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Recepient") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="EditRecepient" Text='
                    <%# Bind("Recepient") %>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="InsertRecepient" Text='
                    <%# Bind("Recepient") %>' />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Edit" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Update" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Insert" Text="Insert" OnClick="insertbutton_click" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="CancelNew" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

sqldatasource code:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [AwardName],[Recepient] FROM [Awards]"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Awards] ([AwardName], [Recepient]) 
                                  VALUES (@AwardName, @Recepient)">
```

Stack Trace

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'AwardName'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753986
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296058
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1379
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +316
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1482
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Comment: Well, it looks like your database column name isn't "AwardName" ...

Comment: Well, I only read the error message, I would suggest you do the same, unlike many users. We're developers after all :-)

Comment: Still getting used to this program. Go easy on the noobs, man

Comment: Well, I wasn't meaning to be offensive so sorry if you understood it that way. Reading the error messages will save you a lot of time, like the time you lost writing this question. Of course some are totally unclear, but in that case the message pointed to your exact problem. I'm easy on beginners, but the fact that the answer was so obvious probably explains why I was the only one to answer your question...

Comment: yeah, for me i just don't know how to effectively read error messages yet.